# share samba drive with windows without having to allow guest access

Tags: windows-10, samba, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set up a simple samba share between my raspberry pi and my windows 10. This is my config:

```
[global]
   min protocol = SMB2
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   wins support = no
   dns proxy = no
   guest account = nobody
   interfaces = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.2.0/24
   bind interfaces only = yes 
   hosts allow = 127.0.0.1 192.168.2.0/24
   hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 1
   max log size = 1000
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   security = user
   server role = standalone server
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   encrypt passwords = yes
   map to guest = never
   usershare allow guests = no
   auto services = pi

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
   directory mask = 0700
   valid users = %S
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
[pi]
   comment = pi samba share
   path = /home/shares/pi
   browseable = yes
   writeable = true
   admin users = pi
   public = no
   valid users = pi
   hide dot files = no
```

In order for this to work, I had to follow this article [Guest access in SMB2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-my/help/4046019/guest-access-in-smb2-disabled-by-default-in-windows-10-and-windows-ser) to change the registry keys for allowing guest access.

What would I need to change in my config so that I don't have change any registry keys for everything to work (meaning: I can successfully access `/home/shares/pi` from my Windows 10)?

I have various settings in my config that, to my understanding, prohibit guest access, so I don't understand why I still had to enable it.

Comment: Why are you against allowing guest access?  If you don't allow it, then you have to configure an authentication server that SAMBA will understand which can be a challenge.

Comment: Here is the [Rabbit Hole](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/333/what-is-the-equivalent-of-active-directory-on-linux) you will fall down by using IdM.

Comment: @Ramhound so it is normal and expected that if I want to setup a samba share between my pi and my windows, I need to tweak the windows registry...?

Comment: Have you considered just enabling SMBv3 instead of using SMBv2?  If you are running an affected edition of Windows 10, then you need to perform these actions, or simply use SMBv3.  However, it only appears that the behavior should effect Education and Enterprise.  **Windows 10 Home and Professional editions are unchanged from their previous default behavior.**  So which edition of Windows 10 are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound what is so challenging about `smbpasswd -a username` ?

Comment: @ivanivan - Besides the fact it’s insecure?

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible approaches:

- You can access the files as guest.
- You can configure accounts that have to authenticate.

A guest account is fine if all the users should have access anyway, but it's not what you desire, so you must configure one ore more accounts. Samba allows different kinds of accounts, they are configured with the `passdb backend` option:

- smbpasswd - The old plaintext passdb backend. Some Samba features will not work if this passdb backend is used. Takes a path to the smbpasswd file as an optional argument.
- tdbsam - The TDB based password storage backend. Takes a path to the TDB as an optional argument (defaults to passdb.tdb in the private dir directory.
- ldapsam - The LDAP based passdb backend. Takes an LDAP URL as an optional argument (defaults to ldap://localhost)

The `smbpasswd` is the oldest and most simple, it's just a plain file similar to `/etc/passwd`. The `tdbsam` uses a binary `tdb` file and can store more information about user accounts. LDAP is more interesting if you want to manage many accounts and/or already have an LDAP server.

See also `smbpasswd` for adding accounts and changing password.